# converting 6B of rows (29 csv files of 20gb each) using AWS

Tags: amazon-emr, aws-glue

How can I convert 6B of rows (29 csv files of 20gb each) using AWS? I need to convert the first column from "19920101|January 1, 1992|Thursday|January|" to "1992-01-01|January 1, 1992|Thursday|January|". I tried using Glue DataBrew but without success.

Comment: There isn't enough detail, can you please elaborate more on the errors?

Comment: Yes sure! I had created another thread dedicated on glue databrew issue. Please you can find here - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=347278&tstart=0. Meanwhile I create this thread to try to find another solution that doesn't necessarily need to be with AWS Glue DataBrew.. In short, my challenge is to convert 6 billion rows using some solution on AWS (all 29 files of 20gb each are there on S3)